# BinarySearch missing required positional arguments

Tags: python

Sorry - still new to Python, but having trouble with my code working. I can't really figure out where to move the declared variables and getting it to work. However, if I put them outside the function, the other functions are ignored and go straight to n's input request. Any way to fix this?

EDIT: Added the entire code and also the errors I am getting at the bottom, I don't know if this is a simple indentation error.

```
# menu selector
from tkinter.tix import Select


select = 0
def DisplayMenu() :
    print ("enter your choice")
    print ("1 for a Linear Search")
    print ("2 for a Binary Search")
    print ("3 for a Bubble Sort")
    print ("4 for a Selection Sort")
    print ("5 for a Insertion Sort")
def SelectRoutine() :
    global select
    DisplayMenu()
    select = int(input())
    if (select == 1) :
        print ("Call the Linear Search Routine")
        LinearSearch()
    elif (select == 2) :
        print ("Call the Binary Search Routine")
        BinarySearch()
    elif (select == 3) :
        print ("Call the Bubble Sort Routine")
        BubbleSort()
    elif (select == 4) :
        print ("Call the Selection Sort")
        SelectionSort()
    elif (select == 5):
        print ("Call the Insertion Sort")
        InsertionSort()
    else :
        print("invalid selection")
def LinearSearch() :
    elements = [10, 20, 80, 70, 60, 50]
    x = int(input("please enter the number to search: "))
    found = False
    for i in range(len(elements)) :
        if(elements[i] == x) :
            found = True
            print("%d found at %dth position" % (x, i))
            break
    if (found == False) :
            print("%d is not in list" % x)
def BinarySearch(n, sortedlist, x) :
    start = 0
    end = n - 1
    for i in range(n) :
        sortedlist.append(int(input("Enter %dth element: " % i)))
    while(start <= end) :
        mid = int((start + end) / 2)
    if (x == sortedlist[mid]) :
        return mid
    elif(x < sortedlist[mid]) :
        end = mid - 1
    else :
        start = mid + 1
        return -1
    n = int(input("Enter the size of the list: "))
    sortedlist = []
    x = int(input("Enter the number to search: "))
    position = BinarySearch(n, sortedlist, x)
    if (position != -1) :
        print("element number %d is present at position: %d" % (x,position))
    else :
        print("element number %d is not present in the list" % x)
SelectRoutine()
```

```
enter your choice
1 for a Linear Search
2 for a Binary Search
3 for a Bubble Sort
4 for a Selection Sort
5 for a Insertion Sort
2
Call the Binary Search Routine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/uglycode.py", line 68, in <module>
    SelectRoutine()
  File "/Users/uglycode.py", line 22, in SelectRoutine
    BinarySearch()
TypeError: BinarySearch() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'n', 'sortedlist', and 'x'
```

[Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwYJW.png)

Comment: Hi. Could you please post the full stack trace Python was giving you, verbatim?

Comment: You've indented everything at and after the `input` so it's part of the function.  Surely that's a typo, fix it.

Comment: The code you've shared is very confusing, it seems to mix user input with the binary search process. Those really shouldn't all be happening mixed together like that. I also suspect a lot of the indentation is wrong....

Comment: Yes, that helps a lot.  Your actual function call is happening in `SelectRoutine`, and you're not passing any parameters in the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass **n, sortedlist, position** variables when you run **BinarySearch** function.

1. You should define variables **n, sortedlist, position** from out of the **BinarySearch** function.
2. Your indent under **while loop** is wrong. You should run **binary search logic** under your **while** function.
3. If you want to run **BinarySearch** function when you want, make it all to one function as **run_binary_search()**

If 1. and 2. are not modified, the code will fall into an infinite loop.

If you apply it to **SelectRoutine()** then, you should define **def BinarySearch()** function like it.

```
def BinarySearch():
    def _binary_serach(n, sortedlist, x):
        start = 0
        end = n - 1
        while (start <= end) :
            mid = int((start + end) / 2)
            if (x == sortedlist[mid]):
                position = mid
                break
            elif(x < sortedlist[mid]):
                end = mid - 1
            else:
                start = mid + 1
                position = -1
        if (position != -1) :
            print("element number %d is present at position: %d" % (x,position))
        else :
            print("element number %d is not present in the list" % x)
        return position

    n = int(input("Enter the size of the list: "))
    sortedlist = []
    for i in range(n):
        sortedlist.append(int(input("Enter %dth element: " % i)))
    x = int(input("Enter the number to search: "))
    position = _binary_serach(n, sortedlist, x)
    return position
```

Comment: Hey Lazyer, thank you for your help! Should this work with the edits I made in the original question? I've included the entire code for full context and the errors I am receiving.

Comment: @youngcrypto I just updated